# Gem corruption: Zip end of central directory signature not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, zip, bundle

i'm new with Ruby and i never used gem files. I had to install offline some gem files. Unfortunately i followed another procedure, instead of following the documentation so i wrote a script to go through the folder "gem" of my installation directory and run first "build" and then "install --force --local ". The "clean" way would have been running just this last command but in the "cache" folder of the installation directory.
I suspect this corrupted my gems. In fact, when running my software (based on this gems) i get this error:

```
/var/lib/gems/2.6.0/gems/rubyzip-1.3.0/lib/zip/central_directory.rb:143:in `get_e_o_c_d': Zip end of central directory signature not found (Zip::Error)
```

The only idea i've is to clean up and re-install the gems, but i know that `bundle clean --force` can not be used that easily, since it can destroy also other gems not related with this last installation.

Do you have any suggestions?
Thank you

Comment: The fastest and cleanest route is to start from a clean slate, which will likely require clearing and re-installing all the gems.

Comment: @dbugger What would be the best way to do it?

Comment: bundle clean --force is a good start